# How to use Android LifecycleOwner in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, lifecycleowner

I want to use mvvm in Dialog but I don't know how to pass `LifecycleOwner` to observe

```
class CommonDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.AppMaskStatusTheme) {

    private val viewBinding: DialogSportOrderBinding by lazy { DialogSportOrderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)) }
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(context as ViewModelStoreOwner)[SportOrderViewModel::class.java] }

 init {
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        viewModel.sportOrderList.observe(***what to pass here?***, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {

        })
    }
}
```

I have tried `context as LifecycleOwner`, `context as AppCompatActivity` but all fail

please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own LifecycleOwner like this

```kotlin
class MyLifecycleOwner() : LifecycleOwner {
    private val mLifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry by lazy { LifecycleRegistry(this) }

    init {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    }

    fun stop() {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    }

    fun start() {
        mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = mLifecycleRegistry
}
```

Then your Dialog class will be like this

```
class CommonDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.AppMaskStatusTheme) {

    private val viewBinding: DialogSportOrderBinding by lazy { DialogSportOrderBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context)) }
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(context as ViewModelStoreOwner)[SportOrderViewModel::class.java] }

    private val lifeCycleOwner: MyLifecycleOwner by lazy { MyLifecycleOwner() }

    init {
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        viewModel.sportOrderList.observe(lifeCycleOwner, {

        })
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        lifeCycleOwner.start()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        lifeCycleOwner.stop()
    }
}
```

Read more about [Lifecycle-Aware Components at here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle)

Comment: That is what i need. Thank for help. It works. Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

`android.content.Context` does not implement `android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner`.

You'd have to pass an instance of `AppCompatActivity`, which implements `android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner` (or any other class which does that).

or cast `(AppCompatActivity) context`, when `context` is an `instanceof AppCompatActivity.`

Comment: I tried to pass `context as AppCompatActivity` but app will crash

Comment: Did you tried     DialogFragment ?

Comment: DialogFragment is ok, but that is different from Dialog.I just want to use dialog